# rpy2: how to call function with parameter in python flask restful?

Tags: python, r, flask, rpy2

in flask-restplus, I am trying to call R function with parameter from Python, where a parameter is coming from POST request JSON body. To do so, first I load R function in python and pass json data as a parameter but I ended up with following error:

> `TypeError: 'ListVector' object is not callable`

I don't understand why, I didn't find much from `rpy2` documentation about function call. Is there any way to pass parameter to R function and call that function in python? Can anyone point me out any possible way to do this? any thought?

**my current attempted code with minimal api**

input json data:

```
{
  "body": {
    "sex": "M",
    "feat_aa": {
      "value": 12,
      "machine": "AC"
    },
    "feat_bb": {
      "value": 13,
      "machine": "AB"
    }
  }
}
```

toy R function:

```
library(jsonlite)

my_func <- function(json_data){
  qry=fromJSON(json_data)
  data=qry$body
  ## do something 
}
```

here is the main code for minimal flask api:

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request
from flask_restplus import Api, Namespace, Resource, fields
import rpy2
import rpy2.robjects as robjects

##
app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)
ns = Namespace('hello') 

features_attr = api.model('hello_world', {
    'value': fields.Integer(required=True),
    'machine': fields.String(required=True)
})

feat_root_objs = api.model('my machine', {
    'sex': fields.String(required=True),
    'features': fields.List(fields.Nested(features_attr, required=True))
    })

@ns.route('/hello')
class helloWorld(Resource):
    @ns.expect(feat_root_objs, validate=False)
    def post(self):
        myfunc = robjects.r.source("my_func.R")
        param = request.get_json()
        res = myfunc(['param'])
        # res = myfunc(param)
        return jsonify(res)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    api.add_namespace(ns)
    app.run(debug=True)
```

How can I pass parameter/arguments to R function and make the function call from python? any thought to make this happen? thanks

**update**

I tried this attempt as well:

```
    def post(self):
        myfunc = robjects.r.source("my_func.R")
        param = request.get_json()
        res = myfunc(param)
        return jsonify({"output": res})
```

but I always have the following error:

```
> [2020-04-29 12:47:02,104] ERROR in app: Exception on
> /Ed_features/match_ed [POST] Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "C:\Users\jyson\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py",
> line 1832, in full_dispatch_request
>     rv = self.dispatch_request()   File "C:\Users\jyson\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py",
> line 1818, in dispatch_request
>     return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)   File "C:\Users\jyson\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Lib\site-packages\flask_restplus\api.py",
> line 309, in wrapper
>     resp = resource(*args, **kwargs)   File "C:\Users\jyson\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Lib\site-packages\flask\views.py",
> line 88, in view
>     return self.dispatch_request(*args, **kwargs)   File "C:\Users\jyson\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Lib\site-packages\flask_restplus\resource.py",
> line 44, in dispatch_request
>     resp = meth(*args, **kwargs)   File "C:\Users\jyson\match_api\imm_server\heylo_ed.py", line 58, in post
>     res = myfunc(param) TypeError: 'ListVector' object is not callable
```

Comment: calling `myfunc(['param'])` passes a list containing the string `param`.  Have you tried `myfunc(param)`.  Also, as you only posted the last line of the traceback, its difficult for someone else to tell which part of your code generated the exception.

Comment: @v25 yes, I tried but I got this error: `TypeError: 'ListVector' object is not callable`. I am desperate about this issue. your kind help would be appreciated.

Comment: @v25 I pasted list of exception that thrown by python. how to solve this? do you have idea? thanks

Comment: I'm sorry I can't help further.  I've managed to re-create this though, in a [more minimal example](https://pastebin.com/AziRDNnz).  I suspect the problem is related to the R function more than the python code.  Feel free to use this to repost/edit.  Perhaps this would be better with the flask related stuff taken out.

Comment: @v25 how do you pass parameter to r function? what's right way to do so? any idea please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you success?
Try :

```
r.source("my_func.R")
my_result=r('my_func')(param)
```

or

```
r.source("my_func.R")
functionR=r('my_func')
my_result=functionR(param)
```